# ComplexExpand absolute squared

Tags: complex

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[a + b I]]
```

Gives

> $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 }$

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[a + b I]^2]
```

On the other hand gives

> Abs[a + I b]^2

How can I let it evaluate to $a^2 + b^2$ instead?

Comment: `FullSimplify[Abs[a + b I]^2, (a | b) \[Element] Reals]` works too.

Comment: I have found that the TargetFunctions approach usually works better for more complicated arguments. Sometimes, running things through FullSimplify is slow and doesn't get you much.

Answer (score 9):

One way is to use

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[a + b I]^2, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
(* a^2 + b^2 *)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that last year. `ComplexExpand` with `TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}` will make an effort to do things like what you show above.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get a slightly better result for `Abs[a + I b]^2` by using an artificial limiting process:

```
ComplexExpand[Limit[Abs[t (a + I b)]^2, t -> 1]]

(* ==> Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2 *)
```

If you don't like this, and also don't like having to specify the `TargetFunctions` option just to get `Abs` to simplify, maybe you'd be better off defining a custom absolute value function that acts like the built-in one but gets simplified more readily:

```
abs[x_] := Sqrt[x Conjugate[x]]

SetAttributes[abs, {NumericFunction, Listable}]

ComplexExpand[abs[a + b I]^2]

(* ==> a^2 + b^2 *)
```

The `SetAttributes` is added just to make the `abs` function act like `Abs` as much as possible, but you could also omit that line.

In general, I don't like using `Abs` because it doesn't always give useful results when you try to take derivatives of variables inside of an `Abs`. You end up with ugly-looking `Abs'` derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in M10, [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) produces the desired result directly:

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[a + b I]^2]
```

> a^2 + b^2