# Why doesn't Abs simplify further?

Tags: assumptions

Why does this:

```
Simplify[Abs[x + I], Element[x, Reals]]
```

give me

```
Abs[x + i]
```

Is there a way to force Mathematica to give me the following answer?

$\sqrt{x^2+1}$

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the tip. But I'll wait for someone to tell me why the above doesn't work

Comment: The fastes way is to use ComplexExpand which assumes that all constants are real: ComplexExpand@Abs[I + x]. Default `ComplexityFunction` is `LeafCount` which gives `6` for `Abs` form and `9` for `Sqrt`, that's why it is left.

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23441/5478)

Comment: Also related: [23867](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23867/complexexpand-absolute-squared)

Answer (score 5):

If you steal the wizard's explanation an apply it to your case

```
cf[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Abs, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]
```

Then

```
FullSimplify[Abs[x + I], x \[Element] Reals, ComplexityFunction -> cf]

(* Sqrt[x^2+1] *)
```

but once again I just copied and vaguely adapted the link provided by kuba

Comment: I understand that LeafCount gives the number of trees in the expression tree. Is there a place where I can read more about it and the ComplexityFunction?

Comment: How about http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html

Comment: how about if you `Count[..,I,..]`? may be more general if it works (sorry cant try frm here)

Comment: @george2079 `cf[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Complex, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]` works too

Comment: You can also type `ComplexityFunction` in the find button on the left above in the menu bar...

Answer (score 3):

How about using `ComplexExpand`

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[x + I]]
```

Gives:

```
Sqrt[1 + x^2]
```